# OleDbCommand INSERT INTO exception- Not a valid file name and Unrecognized database format

Tags: c#, winforms, oledb, oledbconnection

I have got this `OleDbCommand` which should `INSERT INTO` `netpokl.DBF` but it gives this exception - `Not a valid file name`

```
 odcCON.Open();
                     OleDbCommand odc = new OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO netpokl (Castka,Akce) values(@castka,@akce)", odcCON);
                     odc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@castka",textBox2.Text);
                     odc.Parameters.AddWithValue("@akce",vyberradek);

                     odc.ExecuteNonQuery();
                     odcCON.Close();
```

this is the `OleDbConnection`

```
 public static string zapisDBF = "\\\\SERVER\\Transfer\tata\netpokl.DBF";
 OleDbConnection odcCON = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='"+zapisDBF+"'");
```

Solution was:

```
  public static string zapisDBF = @"\\SERVER\Transfer\tata\netpokl.DBF";
```

Another problém occured : Unrecognized database format \SERVER\Transfer\tata\netpokl.DBF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a problem with your string,

```
public static string zapisDBF = "\\\\SERVER\\Transfer\\tata\\netpokl.DBF";
                                          //          ^     ^ missing
```

or simply use verbatim string

```
public static string zapisDBF = @"\\SERVER\Transfer\tata\netpokl.DBF";
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, now i have got this exception: - Unrecognized database format \\SERVER\Transfer\tata\netpokl.DBF . Would you please help me solve it out?

Comment: Try:  `OleDbConnection odcCON = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + zapisDBF + ");` instead.

Comment: @Marek it looks like that the database file is not well-formatted, what database are you using?